# Error:"user does not have pernission to perform this action.Change database context to 'DBName'"

Tags: c#, sql

I want to execute "Create Login 'LoginName' with password='MyPass'" command but i recieve this error : "user does not have permission to perform this action.Change database context to 'DBName'".

how can i solve that?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mission the permission to create a new login.

Check if the user has the permision to:

- ALTER ANY LOGIN

or

- ALTER LOGIN

More info here [CREATE LOGIN (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx)

Comment: i check these two commands and i recieve this error :"The server principal 'Domain\User' is not able to access the database 'DBName' under the current security context."